# UIScrollView position element at bottom of screen, not at bottom of ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm using auto layout and I've got a UIScrollView where I'd like to initially position a UIButton close to the bottom of the screen, independent of the real content size of my ScrollView.

I.e. if the scrollview does not have much content, it should be extended to fill the screen and position the button at the bottom.

If the scrollview has more content than fits on the screen, the button should be positioned at the exact same spot initially, but scroll with the rest of the content.

I tried calculating the height of the visible space, but I can't achieve that with auto layout...

Answer (score 1):

If the button is going to scroll with the rest of the content, then whatever places the content in the scrollView content view has to account for the button's position--otherwise the button will cover up that content or it will cover up the button.

Conveniently for your goal, with scrollViews if the contentView is not more than the frame on either axis, the scrollview won't scroll (because there's nothing to scroll) it will just display.

So inside your scrollview, set your button to be vertically spaced from the superview.top by the amount that, if your button is the highest-Y view, the constrant.constant + button height won't be higher than the scrollview's frame.

If your approach is to add views to thescrollview nad then add contraints to them as they're added, when things get added to the scrollview they need to check if they would overlap the button or be below it, and if so get their vertical constraints attached to the button.bottom or thing attached to the button.bottom and not the superview.top or thing above them attached to the superview.top. If the things are of varying height then this approach is not sustainable because you won't be able to calculate in advance and you need to rethink.

Regardless of where the button lives, if it will scroll with the content then there is no getting around this step: the content needs to be positioned around it or it will overlap some of it or vice-versa.